# getElementsByTagName is not showing anchor tag details in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using react list item to display list of sidebar menu based on role I want to apply styles for the same I am trying to get element by tag name but I am getting empty list from that .
Here is the code :

```
      <ul className="metismenu list-unstyled" ref={refs} id="side-menu">

           {lists.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <Link to={item.link} className={item.submenu ? 'has-arrow' : ''}>
                                <FeatherIcon icon={item.icon} />
                                   <span>{item.name}</span>
                            </Link>
                           {item.submenu ? <SubMenuList menu={item.submenu} /> : ''}
                         </li>
                        );
                    })}
      </ul>



        const initMenu = () => {
        new MetisMenu("#side-menu");
        let matchingMenuItem = null;
        const ul = document.getElementById("side-menu");
        console.log(ul);
        const childNodes = ul.childNodes;
        console.log(childNodes);
        console.log(refs.current);
        const items = refs.current.getElementsByTagName("a");
        console.log(items);
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            if (pathName === items[i].pathname) {
                matchingMenuItem = items[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(matchingMenuItem);
        if (matchingMenuItem) {
            activateParentDropdown(matchingMenuItem);
        }
    };
```

Heres the result:-
[image]

I am getting empty list for anchor tag.

**Edit**

How I am activating dropdown for each element based on router url

```
const activateParentDropdown = useCallback((item) => {
    console.log(item);
    item.classList.add("active");
    const parent = item.parentElement;
    console.log(parent);
    const parent2El = parent.childNodes[1];
    if (parent2El && parent2El.id !== "side-menu") {
        parent2El.classList.add("mm-show");
    }

    if (parent) {
        parent.classList.add("mm-active");
        const parent2 = parent.parentElement;

        if (parent2) {
            parent2.classList.add("mm-show"); // ul tag

            const parent3 = parent2.parentElement; // li tag

            if (parent3) {
                parent3.classList.add("mm-active"); // li
                parent3.childNodes[0].classList.add("mm-active"); //a
                const parent4 = parent3.parentElement; // ul
                if (parent4) {
                    parent4.classList.add("mm-show"); // ul
                    const parent5 = parent4.parentElement;
                    if (parent5) {
                        parent5.classList.add("mm-show"); // li
                        parent5.childNodes[0].classList.add("mm-active"); // a tag
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        scrollElement(item);
        return false;
    }
    scrollElement(item);
    return false;
}, []);
```

Comment: Accessing DOM elements directly in React is an anti-pattern, and even then your should use refs.

Comment: @Keith I tried with useRef also still same issue . I am getting doubt is this coz i am using map ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the code is run directly after returning your jsx it hasn't had time to get to the DOM yet. React updates the DOM asynchronously after having made changes to its virtual DOM...

But: The console.log sometimes fills in values of object after they have been consoled.log, which is probably what is happening for your console.log of refs.current... So at log time it is actually an empty NodeList... but the log get 'updated' after the fact...

So if you changed your code from the line **const items** to

```
const thingsToDo = () => {
  const items = refs.current.getElementsByTagName("a");
  if (items.length === 0) {
    setTimeout(thingsToDo, 10);
    return;
  }
  console.log(items);
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (pathName === items[i].pathname) {
      matchingMenuItem = items[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(matchingMenuItem);
  if (matchingMenuItem) {
    activateParentDropdown(matchingMenuItem);
  }
}
thingsToDo();
```

thus waiting for the elements to exist, things would probably work, although this seems like very 'anti-patternish' React-code - in React you normally use change the values of state variables to rerender a different state, mark a menu choice as active, fold out a submenu etc, not raw DOM parsing and manipulation. But that's up to you to decide.

Hopefully this code solves the immediate problem at hand :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution I achieved part of solution I am able to open submenu but i am not able to close it

Comment: Baby steps... ;)

Comment: Please help me with that or if you have any link please share me it will be very helpfull

Comment: I would to see more code, where you listen for clicks in the submenu, try to close it after click etc in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Chethu:s additional question:

Ok, we are now far from React best practices, but it seems like your submenus are 'always' in the DOM - but being shown by adding the class "mm-show".

So add a delegated event handler that will only be set ONCE in your code make sure it not added twice (maybe inside a useEffect in your main component (App?). When someone clicks the body, check if the click is inside a shown sub menu and then remove the class 'mm-show' from it...

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let shownSubMenu = e.target.closest('.mm-show');
    if (!shownSubMenu) { return; }
    shownSubMenu.classList.remove('mm-show');
    // maybe also remove all mm-active classes from elements
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.mm-active')].forEach(x =>
      x.classList.remove('mm-active'));
  });
}, []);
```

Potentially you always want to hide a submenu after the user clicks *anywhere*, even outside it, if so then do this instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let shownSubMenu = document.querySelector('.mm-show');
    if (!shownSubMenu) { return; }
    shownSubMenu.classList.remove('mm-show');
    // maybe also remove all mm-active classes from elements
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.mm-active')].forEach(x =>
      x.classList.remove('mm-active'))
  })
}, []);
```